# How can we write a good list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

i need some help on the below list comprehension.

Can any one help me guide how can i write the below logic as a good list comprehension?

I have a `v_dms` dictionary which contains key as object and value as list of some other objects.

If I iterate for keys in `v_dms.keys(): print keys.volume_ms`, it gives me the below values

```
 [V<v_id=63, n=TAG-0>]
 [V<v_id=64, n=TAG-0>]
```

I am trying to assign this to a new list comprehension variable.

```
l=[v.v_ms for v in v_dms.keys()]
```

If I am doing the the above operation I am getting a value of 
  `[[V<v_id=63, n=TAG-0>],[V<v_id=64, n=TAG-0>]]` but i need it as

```
  [V<v_id=63, n=TAG-0>,V<v_id=64, n=TAG-0>]
```

Can any one help me in writing a clean list comprehension?
Thank you

Comment: `[v.v_ms[0] for v in v_dms.keys()]`. Each `v.v_ms` value is a single element list (at least in your example); so you want to extract the single value out of it and build the new list with that. Alternatively, if each might have multiple values, check out `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, or just use a nested comprehension: `[w for v in v_dms.keys() for w in v.v_ms]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested list comprehension will help you here

```
l = [obj for vol_ms in v_dms.keys() for obj in vol_ms.v_ms]
```